# How do I solve error 302 when web scraping?

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I'm currently working on a web scraping project using Scrapy to extract financial data from MarketWatch's website. However, I've run into a problem where my spider is encountering redirection issues and is unable to access the financial data pages.

When I try to access the financial data URLs using Scrapy's `Request` method, I'm getting redirected multiple times and receiving a status code 302 (redirect). Here's a snippet from the log:

2023-08-20 18:53:23 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET [https://www.marketwatch.com/search?q=financials>](https://www.marketwatch.com/search?q=financials%3E) from <GET [https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/abbv/financials>](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/abbv/financials%3E)
2023-08-20 18:53:23 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET [https://www.marketwatch.com/search?q=financials>](https://www.marketwatch.com/search?q=financials%3E) from <GET [https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/adbe/financials>](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/adbe/financials%3E)
2023-08-20 18:53:23 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET [https://www.marketwatch.com/search?q=financials>](https://www.marketwatch.com/search?q=financials%3E) from <GET [https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/acn/financials>](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/acn/financials%3E)
...

I've verified the URL structure, and it seems correct. I'm not sure why these redirections are occurring, as the `robots.txt` file doesn't seem to disallow access to the financial data URLs.

I've also confirmed that the `{ticker}` variable in the URL is being replaced correctly, as I've printed it along with the generated URLs.

Could someone provide some insights into why these redirection issues might be occurring? Is there a specific header or setting I should be using in my Scrapy requests to prevent these redirects? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I tried going over all the code,  but couldn't solve it .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 302 is not an error.  It simply means that the website received your request and it decided that it wanted to send you to a different url.  I don't see anything in your question that looks like an actual error.

Comment: I see, but why is it redirecting and how can i prevent it? Or is it just nothing to do about it as it is in the website's hands?

Comment: THere is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: _is it just nothing to do about it as it is in the website's hands?_ Yes, exactly.

Comment: Sometimes websites will reorganize their urls into a new structure, and when a request is received for a url in the old structure, the website will redirect you to the new url by responding with a 302, as a courtesy.  But that's just one reason why the website might issue a 302 response -- there are hundreds of possibilities.